# How to select a specific property from array

Tags: php

I am using the Twitter API with this code:

```
 $statuses = $connection->get("favorites/list", ["screen_name" => "Ali" , "count" => 2 ]);
 print_r ($statuses);
```

Which gives this result:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [created_at] => Sun Jun 28 04:56:55 +0000 2020 [id] => 1277103662918238210 [id_str] => 1277103662918238210 [text] => @mu11igan @LAGallday @ali The Church has always been tied to buildings. The Temple (here and the one in heaven.),sy… [truncated] => 1 [entities] => stdClass Object ( [hashtags] => Array ( ) [symbols] => Array ( ) [user_mentions] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object
```

But I would like to display only one specific element;
for example only this one  `[id_str] => 1277103662918238210`

Comment: use `$array[0][id_str];`

Comment: @KUMAR I believe $arr[0]['id_str']

Comment: use: `echo $arr[0]->id_str;` - `id_str` is a property of an object inside the array (`$arr`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do simply like this.

```
$retValue = {};
$retValue['id_str'] = $statuses[0][id_str]; // or $statuses[0]->id_str

print_r($retValue); // or echo(json_encode($retValue))
```

Hope this helps you to understand.

Comment: please explain about `{};` symbol.